# Does the colour of turban in India have any specific meaning?

Tags: history, culture

The above question is posed as far as the following photo is concerned..

[image: photo of 3 men in turbans]

Answer (score 0):

The following extracs highlights some of the importance of colours associated with turbans, which is defined by the Sanskrit term "Uṣṇīṣa":

> Āpastamba-śrautasūtra recommends a white turban for a king who performs Rājasūya. In Purāṇas Śiva is described in several places with Uṣṇīṣa having colours white, yellow and black. Similarly, Brahma is depicted as wearing a white one. From Mahābhāṣya we learn that priests wore Uṣṇīṣa of red colour.

The [source includes further references](https://www.wisdomlib.org/history/essay/cosmetics-costumes-and-ornaments-in-ancient-india/d/doc1146457.html).

Comment: thanks, but none of the colours mentioned in the excerpt are actually observed on the above photo. What is the meaning of orange or black turban?

Comment: @JimmyBionic given the fact that the men in the picture are also sporting long-beards, this indicates that they are not Hindus, but are actually Sikhs. So it is very unlikely that you will get your answer here.